# addEventListener click for Unordered List

Tags: javascript, html

Attempting to convert a for loop that steps through an unordered list of hyperlinks adding an 'onclick' function to each into one using an eventlistener for an assignment. I have been unable to get a working model.

Here is the navlist and links I am working with, note that these I cannot edit or change in any way.

```
    <body>

<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="l0"> <a href="#">Sniffer</a>    </li>
    <li id="l1"> <a href="#">is</a> </li>
    <li id="l2"> <a href="#">good</a> </li>
    <li id="l3"> <a href="#">programmer</a> </li>
</ul>
<script>

var myLinks = [
                'http://bing.com/search?q=Sniffer',
                'http://bing.com/search?q=is',
                'http://bing.com/search?q=good',
                'http://bing.com/search?q=programmer'
                ];
```

And here is the code sample that I am converting:

```
window.onload=function() {

  for (var i=0; i< myLinks.length; i++) {
    // document.getElementById("l"+i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0]).href=myLinks[i];
      document.getElementById("l"+i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick=(function(idx) {
      var idx = i;
      return function() {  
        window.location.href = myLinks[idx]; 
        return false; // cancel href
        }; 
    })(i);      
  }
}
</script> 
</body>
```

I have attempted a few different ways of formatting the specific document elements in the concatenation. but none of them work. Here is my most recent and simplest attempt:

```
window.onload=function() {

  for (var i=0; i< myLinks.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("l"+i).addEventListener("click", function() {
      var idx = i;
      return function() {  
        window.location.href = myLinks[idx]; 
        return false; // cancel href
        }; 
    })(i);      
  }
}
```

I very much need help with this as I have tried to work with this code for a decent number of hours. I don't really even understand what the code is doing to be able to convert to a click event. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var myLinks = [
    'http://bing.com/search?q=Sniffer',
    'http://bing.com/search?q=is',
    'http://bing.com/search?q=good',
    'http://bing.com/search?q=programmer'];

window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = myLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
        document.getElementById("l" + i).addEventListener("click", (function (idx) {
            return function () {
                window.location.href = myLinks[idx];
                return false; // cancel href
            };
        })(i));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. Although the parse formatting is unneeded in my current setup, this worked. I couldn't understand the issue with my code and I see now that while using an IIFE within the eventlistener parameters I do not need to add the return function.

Comment: This actually isn't a perfect answer for me, I now noticed that the enclosure was eliminated. I must preserve the enclosure for this assignment.

Comment: @Sniffer I've updated the answer. The problem lies in your function closure.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is a nice solution to this problem:

```
var myLinks = [
    'http://bing.com/search?q=Sniffer',
    'http://bing.com/search?q=is',
    'http://bing.com/search?q=good',
    'http://bing.com/search?q=programmer'
];

var list = document.getElementById('list');

list.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    if (event.target && event.target.nodeName === "A") {
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(list.children, event.target.parentNode);
        var href = myLinks[index];
        console.log('link to ' + href + ' was clicked.');
        // window.location = href;
    }

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpmh4L5m/)

Comment: The for loop cannot be circumvented, this is an assignment in an HTML5 class so unfortunately my options are limited. I have also never encountered: 
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(list.children, event.target.parentNode);
And hence, cannot use it as a solution. It must be similar to my current solution. I am doing something wrong in that solution and that is what I need to know.